# Firebase: Anyway not to have whole server data base mirrored locally?

Tags: firebase

I am looking for a solution to a shared database problem and firebase seems to be an interesting solution.

I want all local database data to be pushed to the server, but I don't want everything on the server to be stored locally. Sure I need shared data for things like messages etc but I only want local data to be a subset of the online database (specifically things that pertain or are shared with the user).

Maybe I am confused about this statement *"synchronized in realtime to every connected client"* but if everything from the server is also mirrored locally then a massive amount of redundant data stored locally that will never be accessed, eg other users personal.

Can Firebase handle what I want to do? If no what other solutions would you recommend?

Regards,
Nate

Answer (score 3):

Firebase will only synchronize data that you actively listen for.

Say that your Firebase app is called `natesapp` and you have a data structure like this:

```
/
    users
       uid_for_nate
           fullName: "Nate Uni"
           nickName: "Nate"
           stackoverflowId: 484786
       uid_for_puf
           fullName: "Frank van Puffelen"
           stackoverflowId: 209103
    messages
        pushid_1
           creator: "uid_for_nate"
           nickName: "Nate"
           text: "Firebase: Anyway not to have whole server data base mirrored locally?"
        pushid_2
           creator: "uid_for_puf"
           nickName: "puf"
           text: "Firebase will only synchronize data that you actively listen for."
        pushid_3
           creator: "uid_for_nate"
           nickName: "Nate"
           text: "Ah cool. That helps. Thanks!"
```

### Synchronizing the entire database

If you attach a listener like this:

```
ref = new Firebase('https://natesapp.firebaseio.com');
ref.on('value', function(snapshot) {
    console.log(snapshot.val());
})
```

Then Firebase will indeed synchronize the entire database and keep it in memory. It does so because *you told it to do so*.

### Synchronizing only the data you need

A better approach is to only synchronize the data your app actually need.

If you just want to display a list of messages, you'd:

```
ref = new Firebase('https://natesapp.firebaseio.com');
ref.child('messages').on('value', function(snapshot) {
    console.log(snapshot.val());
})
```

And now Firebase will only synchronize the messages, which in this case contain all the information needed to show a simple list.

```
ref.child('messages').limitToLast(10).on('value', function(snapshot) {
    console.log(snapshot.val());
})
```

If you also want to show the currently authenticated user's full name you'd add a second listener:

It's probably a good idea to specify a maximum number of messages to load, to reduce the memory further:

```
ref = new Firebase('https://natesapp.firebaseio.com');
ref.child('messages').on('value', function(snapshot) {
    console.log(snapshot.val());
})
```

And you'd still only be synchronizing the messages and a single user.

Note that all this type of information is pretty well described in [Firebase's programming guide](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/guide/). Spending an hour or two on that, will save you (and me) a ton of time here.

Comment: Thanks again for your reply Frank. I think that perhaps the question was not clear enough or I have misinterpreted your answer. 1. I want everything locally to be sent to the server, so server represents is an aggregate that reflects all mobile databases (redundancy and interaction). 2. I do not want an exact local copy of the server's database to be mirrored locally across each mobile device. That would represent a large out of redundant information that the local user doesn't need to have stored locally. When reading the documentation it was not clear if this was possible with Firebase.

Comment: The answer from Frank is pretty clear on this. In other words he says: "everything stored locally will be sent to the server, everything you attached a listener on will be mirrored locally". Your question and Frank's answer was exactly what I was searching for.